# Play and Stop Audio File with Javascript onmouseenter & onmouseleave

Tags: javascript, audio, mouseevent

Looking to use just Javascript without any libraries to start and stop audio on mouse enter and mouse leave. Also want the audio to loop while the div is being hovered. Right now I have two divs because I'm unsure of how to add multiple `onmouseenter` events and if this is even possible. Is all of this possible? Dropping my code snippet below.

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){
  myFunction(event);
});

var mouse;
var cursor = document.getElementById("cursor");

function myFunction(e){
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
  cursor.style.left = (mouseX-55) + "px";
  cursor.style.top = (mouseY-55) + "px";
}

function play() {
  var audio = new Audio('https://www.figurefoundry.xyz/metal/metaldrums.mp3');
  audio.play();
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #fffdfa;
}

#cursor {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 9999999;
  pointer-events: none; /* pointer-events: none is needed */
  cursor: none;
  animation: spincursor infinite 1.5s steps(1, end);
}

div {
  background: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px;
  cursor: none;
}


@keyframes spincursor {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  12.5% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  37.5% {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  62.5% {
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
  87.5% {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.figurefoundry.xyz/metal-cursor.svg" id="cursor" hidden></img>

<div onmouseenter="play()">
  <div onmouseenter="cursor.hidden = false" onmouseleave="cursor.hidden=true">
  </div> <!--make cursor invisible on leave and visible on enter-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to get an error in console if you do this in Chrome: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first` You need to interact ( click) something for audio to be played .

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: is it possible to force a click onmouseenter?